# How do I get a picture from website when I cannot find <img> tag?

Tags: html, image, web, web-scraping

On http://internet.org there is an image of a world map showing internet access across the world.

I like this image and want to get it. I cannot use take a screenshot because there is text in the way. I can't find any  tags. How do I obtain the image?

Comment: go here : https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851586_236045159890577_1605622836_n.jpg

Comment: ah wow thank you. How did you find it?

Comment: As said by both answers I used chrome developer tools to find the background image url. I hope you have permision to use that image though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have developer tools on your browser, you can right click and then `inspect element`.

It will come up with something like this (assuming you're using chrome).

[image]

Here is Firefox's dev tools:

[image]

On the right, you can see there are CSS properties. Under `background-image:` you see there is a `url` and then a link to a photo.

That photo is the world map.

Here is the image link: [Here](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851586_236045159890577_1605622836_n.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's called in the CSS as a `background-image:url('?');` ? So look for `background-image` in the site's CSS.